# Problem setting up SPF

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, email, spf

So SPF seems to be the backscatter-saviour, the only problem is setting it up is a real pain.

I've got a VPS and use GoDaddy as my domain manager.

I set up this SPF record:

`v=spf1 mx include:host.be include:host.com include:host.net include:host.org include:host.info include:host2.biz include:host3.com -all`

and I get this error message when trying it out on http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html:

`Permanent Error SPF Permanent Error: include has trivial recursion: include:host.be`

So what's wrong?

Also: Is setting up an SPF record enough, or do I also need to add some functionality to the server?

Comment: Those don't look like real domain names to me, so I suspect you've anonymised them. You'll need to give us the real data to get an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so for your domain you have "include:host.be"
Check that host.be SPF records don't include/refer to your domain.

Comment: So they can't be on the other domain? But host.be can send mails for host.com and the other way around...

Comment: they just can't recursively include each other